# Azure App Service - Site Not Found Only From Specific Locations

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

We have a website hosted via Azure App Service that we can access from many of our locations throughout the world.

Yet there are some locations that return

> "This site can't be reached" (ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED).

Any ideas?

Cannot ping the IP address from the client PC either.
In Azure, I have all IP Addresses open in the Firewall.

I feel like I have exhausted everything so far.

I also activated the site through another server that is not part of Azure and I was able to access it from locations that cannot access the Azure Site.  Why I'm pretty sure it is an Azure issue (unless it is their provider blocking something)?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an Azure issue. Rather, it sounds like a potential dns issue (or specific networking issues) from specific machines (or locations). Could it be possible the IP address has been blocked because of another malicious site? Just one of many potential reasons. But Azure is not going to block client access unless you specifically choose to do so.

All that aside: Unfortunately this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Might be worth asking on Super User or Server Fault, where someone might be able to help diagnose your network issues.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am looking into the DNS part now.  This is a public facing site (www.scaleitusa.com) and it has been hit or miss with people being able to load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED is a DNS failure error. If you have recently changed the DNS of your domain, it should take a while to become available in all regions.

If you've already changed for quite a time, check if the computer where you are trying to access is having any other DNS errors / change DNS servers to known public service (Google/Cloudflare/OpenDNS).

As you can see here, your DNS is failing in several regions:
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.scaleitusa.com